# Getting type error while integrating fullcalender using Jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am facing one issue. I am getting the following error while integrating full calender using Jquery.

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.isValid is not a function
    at X (moment.min.js:6)
    at String.kc (moment.min.js:6)
    at e (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at d (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
    at c (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
    at Object.t [as formatDate] (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (cal.html:15)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Fullcalendar Integration with example</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.3.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.3.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet"  media="print" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.3.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
        var st=$.fullCalendar.formatDate('2018-01-03', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
        var end=$.fullCalendar.formatDate('2018-01-05', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
        var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({  
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
            navLinks: true, 
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, 
            events: [
                {
                    title  : 'event1',
                    start  : '2017-04-01'
                },
                {
                    title  : 'event2',
                    start  : st,
                    end    : end
                },
                {
                    title  : 'event3',
                    start  : '2017-04-09T12:30:00',
                    allDay : false // will make the time show
                }
            ],  // request to load current events

        });

     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here actually I need to display the `event bar`  `start date to end date (i.e-'2018-01-03' and '2018-01-05')` but it is showing the the above error. Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's an issue with the variables. Instead of using Full Calendar for them, just use Moment JS.

So you should be able to change them to:

```
var st = moment().format('2018-01-03', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
var end = moment().format('2018-01-06', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
```

Updated with end date set as plus 1 day, to show it for the correct dates.

Comment: error cleared but issue is still there the event bar is not ending at the particular end date (`'2018-01-05'`) its ending before date.

Comment: It looks like an issue with a time not being present. If you add a time parameter like `2018-01-05T12:30:00` it works but also displays the time. With the end date it looks like it's ending at midnight on the 5th and therefore for some reason not counting it. You could alternatively just add 1 to the day, so it would become `2018-01-06`.

Comment: Can you fix it and change in your post.

Comment: Here Only the static data but when I will change the `start and end date dynamically means start=2018-01-03` how to achive this.

Comment: I did as per you and title bar is also finished at right date but title is changed from `event2` to `12a event2` which is wrong.

Comment: All I can think of then is setting the end date as plus one day. I've updated my answer to include this. Not ideal, but I can't think of another solution. This will display it for the correct dates.

Comment: This "error" with end dates is not an error, it's the documented behaviour. End dates are **exclusive**. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ If you search around SO there are quite a few past questions about that specific issue.

Comment: As I noted in my answer, the lines `var st = moment().format('2018-01-03', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"); var end = moment().format('2018-01-06', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");` are completely redundant and produce exactly the same output as was given as the input. It's simply not necessary to call this function for this use case. The answer works but is not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

These statements:

```
var st=$.fullCalendar.formatDate('2018-01-03', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
var end=$.fullCalendar.formatDate('2018-01-05', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
```

do not work. This function is no longer current in fullCalendar, it was removed in v2.0. It still appears you can call it, but it's no longer documented and you shouldn't expect it to work in any predictable or correct way.

Even if it *did* work, your usage of it is redundant because you're asking for your string to be formatted into exactly the same format it already is (the `H:mm:ss` part is irrelevant because your date string doesn't have a time component, so no time string would be output either).

The current method of doing this in fullCalendar (`var st = moment().format('2018-01-03', "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");` - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/) also produces simply `2018-01-03` - identical to the input. There's no need to use this at all.

Instead you can just specify the time in your event directly:

```
{
  title  : 'event2',
  start  : "2018-01-03",
  end    : "2018-01-05"
}
```

This is possible because fullCalendar accepts for dates anything which momentJS accepts - including ISO strings, native JS Date objects etc.

Regarding the secondary issue you mentioned in the comments of another question, your date does not appear on the 5th Jan day in the calendar, because end dates are **exclusive** (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/). Your event finishes at the beginning of the 5th, not the end of it. If you want to make it appear on the Friday, simply add one day to the end date (`2018-01-06`).